# Class instantiations in cpp

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

If I have a header class in C++, what do the 
class ColorData and class PixelBuffer instantiations do? Does it mean the header file recognizes these other classes, are parents of the header class, or something else? The class i'm currently in is BrushWorkApp.h

```
#ifndef BRUSHWORKAPP_H
#define BRUSHWORKAPP_H
#include "BaseGfxApp.h"
class ColorData;
class PixelBuffer;

class BrushWorkApp : public BaseGfxApp {//more stuff in here}
```

Comment: These are *forward declarations*. They say that there are classes that are called that way so that the compiler knows that e.g. `ColorData *` is some type.

Answer (score 2):

This is called a forward-declaration and is pretty similar to declarations of functions without a body:

Basically it tells the Compiler "Those two symbols refer to classes." Without further specifying how the classes look. Due to this, you are limited in using them, e.g. you can use them as parameters, pointers or template arguments but you can't use any members of the classes.

Comment: one more question, would this mean BaseGfxApp is a parent class of BrushWorkApp?

Comment: Yup, its a public base class, meaning that public members of BaseGfxApp will stay public in BrushWorkApp.